# Fixing formatting by removing MathJaX formatting

Tags: bug

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/714/180) is not entirely readable as two "\$" signs are interpreted as a MathJaX block and the formatting is messed up. I tried to fix it by replacing "$115" with "\$115" but got validation error that my edit should be at least 6 characters long. What are my options here to fix the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, thanks for bringing this to our attention! The escape code for MathJax Tex and LaTex is `\` or  a backslash in front of the dollar sign `$`, so what I did is replace all the dollar signs when used as currency signs with `\$`. More is explained in the [MathJax Tex and LaTex documentation in the *"TeX and LaTeX math delimiters"* paragraph](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html).

Alternatively, any formatting by the Stack Exchange hypertext parser can be escaped by either using inline code blocks encapsulated within backticks `` ` or a complete code block by starting the line with four space characters (but that's not really suitable for this case). More info about formatting tricks can be read in the [Markdown Editing Help](https://space.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

To bypass the minimum change requirement, the easiest trick is to simply insert a few HTML encoded non-breaking space characters (`&nbsp;`), either at the end of the text, or by replacing the already existing spaces. It's a hack, so don't tell anyone. ;)